# 32 bit windows service on 64 bit machine

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003

I am having problem in running windows service of 32 bit on 64 bit windows server, query that i have is as following

1) will there be any problem if a windows service( using all 32 bit DLL's) is running on a 64 bit widows server??

2) If yes then how can we make a windows service of 32 bit run on windows server 2003 R2.
every time i try to run the service event log shows me error that attempt a load a program that is with incorrect format.( Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Can this be a problem of service having any of its dll's of 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely run a 32-bit service on a 64-bit Windows OS.

> can this be a problem of service having any of its dll's of 64 bit?

If the service cannot find a 32-bit version of DLLs that it references, it would fail to load.  If the service is written with managed code, use the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Fuslogvw) to see if there are any binding failures.

Comment: Thanks for your previous answer.
How can i check for oracle DataAccess inside assembly folder is of 64 or 32 bit ??. This is regarding the same problem i am having.